# Print applied to one page only

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I used the following code to print the HTML table in ASP.NET MVC:

```
function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;

    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;

    return false;
}
```

This works perfectly and prints my html table as expected. But the problem is if my table have a lot of rows and more than one page it prints just one page and ignores the rest. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you can get other pages by ajax request, then append all results to one page.

Comment: @Eisa I can see all rows in MVC view but when it prints, just prints one page and first rows of the table.

Comment: Have you gone through with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505006/printing-huge-table-with-window-print-only-prints-one-page
&
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845621/window-print-is-not-printing-the-whole-page ?

You may find some relevant stuff in those links.

Comment: @manika Yes. I tried all of them already but none of them seem to works for me.

Comment: you could use CSS to create a printable view of the page, instead, using media queries.