# C# EPPLUS - print excel file

Tags: c#, printing, epplus

hellow, I use EPPLUS-ExcelPackageClass and I would like to print a worksheet ? I found only a functions of the settings: public sealed class ExcelPrinterSettings : XmlHelper (for example: BlackAndWhite,BottomMargin,Draft,FitToHeight,PaperSize,PrintArea, Etc..) , what is the final command to print the file to the printer ?, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on this answer, there is no printing method: [Print command in EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814447/print-command-in-epplus)

You can try to convert it PDF or print with Office Excel app.

Comment: Thanks, I have not found a function that prints , and i used Epplus driver instead of Excel.Application because it takes some time to open Excel files in Excel.Application and Epplus opens quickly , by the way my program is winform not web.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you can print to PDF using EPPlus.  You can do it using Excel.  If that would be beneficial to you, here is syntax that would achieve such (I used Excel 2013 and pdfcreator)

And what this does is saves the pdf in the location C:\ExcelPDF then adds an Underscore then appends todays date in the mmddyyyy format to the end of the filename.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat (Type: Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, 
Filename: "C:\ExcelPDF_" + 
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".pdf", 
Quality: XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, OpenAfterPublish: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert it to pdf and then print it and To convert the worksheet in an Excel file into a PDF file, you can use the EPPlus library that enables you to export the page as a PDF file, using the WorksheetToPdfConverter function that converts the page into a PDF file and saves it to the hard disk. The following code can be used:

```
public void ExcelWorksheetToPdf(string excelFilePath, string sheetName, string pdfFilePath)
{
    // Load Excel workbook
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFilePath)))
    {
        // Get worksheet by name
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];

        // PDF converter
        ExcelToPdfConverter converter = new ExcelToPdfConverter(worksheet);

        // Convert worksheet to PDF and save to file
        File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, converter.Convert());
    }
}
```

After That, the PDF file can be printed using the print dialog using the following code:

```
public void PrintPdfFileWithDialog(string pdfFilePath)
{
    // Create a process to open the PDF file
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pdfFilePath;

    // Start the process
    process.Start();

    // Wait for the process to finish loading the PDF file
    process.WaitForInputIdle();

    // Open the print dialog
    process.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/p \"" + pdfFilePath + "\"";
    process.Start();

    // Wait for the process to finish printing
    process.WaitForExit();

    // Close the process
    process.Close();
}
```